# How to login to a site using POST request? (Swift,iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, post, http-headers, alamofire

I want to create an iOS Application that logs into a [website](https://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfLoginPage.aspx) and parses the data from several pages of that site, while maintaining the login session.This is what I have done so far. I send a GET request to retrieve the EVENTVALIDATON and VIEWSTATE parameters required for the POST request. (I looked at the POST by using 'Firebug'). When I run the following code, it gives back the same login page. But it should be giving me [this page](http://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfStudMenu.aspx).

```
    var parameter: Parameters = [:]
    var viewstate: String = ""
    var eventvalidation: String = 


    @IBAction func postRequest(_ sender: Any) {


    Alamofire.request("https://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfLoginPage.aspx").responseString { response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        if let html = response.result.value {
            if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                // Search for nodes by CSS selector

                for show in doc.css("input[id='__VIEWSTATE']") {
                    self.viewstate=show["value"]!
                    //print(show["value"] as Any)
                }

                for show in doc.css("input[id='__EVENTVALIDATION']") {
                    self.eventvalidation=show["value"]!
                    //print(show["value"] as Any)
                }
            }
        }
        //creating dictionary for parameters
        self.parameter = ["__EVENTTARGET":"",
                         "__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
                         "__LASTFOCUS":"",
                         "__VIEWSTATE":self.viewstate,
                         "__EVENTVALIDATION":self.eventvalidation,
                         "rdolst":"S",
                         "Txtstudid":"<myrollno>",
                         "TxtPasswd":"<mypassword>",
                         "btnlogin":"Login"
        ]
    }
    Alamofire.request ("https://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfLoginPage.aspx",method: .post, parameters: self.parameter, headers: headers).responseString { response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        print(response)
    }
```

To be honest, I'm very new to requests and parsing data(I have finished the parsing part separately though). I did some more research and read about headers and cookies.So after checking the headers, the initial GET request by the browser has a response header of

```
Cache-Control :   private
Content-Encoding :   gzip
Content-Length :   4992
Content-Type :   text/html; charset=utf-8
Date :   Sun, 18 Jun 2017 14:25:50 GMT
Server :    Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie :   .ASPXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 18:30:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary :   Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version :   4.0.30319
X-Powered-By :   ASP.NET
```

and Request Header of

```
Accept :    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding :   gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language :   en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection :   keep-alive
Cookie :   ASP.NET_SessionId=urzugt0zliwkmz3ab1fxx1ja
Host :   ecampus.psgtech.ac.in
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests :   1
User-Agent :   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0`
```

The problem is I don't understand how a initial GET request can have a token with it. If request happens first, response should be the one containing the token? I don't know what I am doing wrong and how to get this working. I don't know if I am missing something altogether. I came here only after trying everything I could think of. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVENTVALIDATON and VIEWSTATE parameters required for the POST <--

But in your code the POST request is executed immediately after the GET request, at this point the self.parameter is empty

Alamofire has **asynchronous** completionHandler

Wait for the GET request to complete, and then send the POST request:

```
var parameter: Parameters = [:]
    var viewstate: String = ""
    var eventvalidation: String = 


@IBAction func postRequest(_ sender: Any) {


Alamofire.request("https://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfLoginPage.aspx").responseString { response in
    print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
    if let html = response.result.value {
        if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            // Search for nodes by CSS selector

            for show in doc.css("input[id='__VIEWSTATE']") {
                self.viewstate=show["value"]!
                //print(show["value"] as Any)
            }

            for show in doc.css("input[id='__EVENTVALIDATION']") {
                self.eventvalidation=show["value"]!
                //print(show["value"] as Any)
            }
        }
    }
    //creating dictionary for parameters
    self.parameter = ["__EVENTTARGET":"",
                     "__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
                     "__LASTFOCUS":"",
                     "__VIEWSTATE":self.viewstate,
                     "__EVENTVALIDATION":self.eventvalidation,
                     "rdolst":"S",
                     "Txtstudid":"15i231",
                     "TxtPasswd":"OpenSesame",
                     "btnlogin":"Login"
    ]

    //Wait for the GET request to complete, and then send the POST request: <<==
    Alamofire.request ("https://ecampus.psgtech.ac.in/studzone/AttWfLoginPage.aspx",method: .post, parameters: self.parameter, headers: headers).responseString { response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        print(response)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that the requests were asynchronous. I added the POST request to the completion handler of the first request and it logged in! Thanks

Comment: I'm am doing this for a website I must login to. It looks like I'm able to get a good response after the **POST** with the correct parameters. Then I send a new request with a **GET** for another page, using the **ASP.NET_SessionId** and the answer tells me to login. I've checked that what I'm sending is identical to the browser with no luck. Any idea of why I would get a positive result immediately followed by failure? Thanks in advance

Comment: After playing with the issue for the whole day. (No solution yet): I'm able to cascade 3 Alamofire requests, and sometimes it will work, other times it responds with an HTML asking to login. I also noticed if I log in with safari and send that ASP.NET_SessionId through Swift, it will work everytime. Not sure what I'm missing here but I'd like to do the whole process through iOS.